# Latitude longitude picker using google maps and lazarus

Tags: google-maps, lazarus

I am desigining a simple geolocation application in witch the user must select it's location.

I was wondering if there is any way I can access google maps or any other map to display a map and allow the user to select his location by clicking on it.

I have managed to do this with Delphi using the TWebbrowser but I am looking for a cross platform solution.

Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: How about HTML5 geolocation?

Comment: @Cdeez Might be a good idea, haven't tried it tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a way. Look for TMapViewer on Google Code.

Features:

- Google Maps: Normal, Satellite, Hybrid, Physical, Physical hybrid
- OpenStreet based maps: OpenStreetMap Mapnik, OpenStreetMap Osmrenderer, OpenCycleMap
- Virtual Earth: Normal, Aerial, Road, Hybrid
- Yahoo: Normal, Satellite, Hybrid
- Nokia Ovi: Normal, Satellite, Hybrid, Physical
- lots of debug information
- pluggable download engine (synapse, native win32)
- basic thread based downloading

Link: [Get them from Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/mapviewer/source/browse?repo=default)

Cheers!!!

Comment: I have implemented the MapViewer in my Lazarus but I can't find any example how to use it